# Spring, CORS, and j_spring_security_logout

Tags: java, spring, cors

I need to use CORS with Spring Security.  I've succeeded in getting login and basic security working, using a OncePerRequestFilter that is configured in app-beans.xml as follows:

```
<bean id="corsAwareAuthenticationFilter"class="org.broadinstitute.portal.servlet.CorsAwareAuthenticationFilter"/>
<security:http use-expressions="true">
  <security:custom-filter ref="corsAwareAuthenticationFilter" after="PRE_AUTH_FILTER"/>
...
```

I basically followed the approach in this question: [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing with Spring Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18264334/cross-origin-resource-sharing-with-spring-security)

My configuration for logout in app-beans.xml is simply:

```
    <security:logout delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"/>
```

This works fine without CORS.

My problem is logging out.  CORS is stopping access to j_spring_security_logout.  Any idea why my OncePerRequestFilter is being called when logging in, but not when logging out?

Edited to add:

Thanks to alain.janinm, I solved the problem.  I needed to set my filter to be called before the LOGOUT_FILTER.  The following configuration addition solved the problem:

```
    <security:custom-filter ref="corsAwareAuthenticationFilter" before="LOGOUT_FILTER"/>
```

Note, using position="LOGOUT_FILTER" didn't work, as that put my filter in the same position as the Spring LOGOUT_FILTER.  My filter doesn't do the same thing as the LOGOUT_FILTER -- all mine does is to add the CORS headers.  So I actually need the Spring LOGOUT_FILTER to still be called.

Comment: I think you have to define a custom-filter with the position "LOGOUT_FILTER". Something like that : `<security:custom-filter position="LOGOUT_FILTER" ref="yourCORSlogoutFilter" />`

Comment: alain.janinm, thank you so much for pointing me towards the solution.  I've edited my question to add the solution.

Comment: You're welcome! I suggest you post your edit as an answer (you can answer your own questions) and then mark it as accepetd, it will be clearer for future users with the same pb. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to alain.janinm, I solved the problem. I needed to set my filter to be called before the LOGOUT_FILTER. The following configuration addition solved the problem:

```
<security:custom-filter ref="corsAwareAuthenticationFilter" before="LOGOUT_FILTER"/>
```

Note, using position="LOGOUT_FILTER" didn't work, as that put my filter in the same position as the Spring LOGOUT_FILTER. My filter doesn't do the same thing as the LOGOUT_FILTER -- all mine does is to add the CORS headers. So I actually need the Spring LOGOUT_FILTER to still be called.