# Spring Boot and CSRF with AngularJS - Forbitten 403 -> wrong logout

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, csrf, csrf-protection

In my Spring Boot/AngularJS application I have the following CSRF- Configuration:

```
@Override
protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository());    http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

    final String[] restEndpointsToSecure = WebSecurityConfig.restEndpointsToSecure;
    for (final String endpoint : restEndpointsToSecure) {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/" + endpoint + "/**").hasRole(UserRoleEnum.USER.toString());
    }

    http.addFilterAfter(csrfTokenResponseHeaderBindingFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);

    xAuthTokenConfigurer.setDetailsService(userDetailsServiceBean());
    final SecurityConfigurer<DefaultSecurityFilterChain, HttpSecurity> securityConfigurerAdapter = xAuthTokenConfigurer;
    http.apply(securityConfigurerAdapter);
}
```

The CSRF- Token Filter looks like this:

```
@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, javax.servlet.FilterChain filterChain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    final CsrfToken csrf = (CsrfToken)request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class.getName());
    if (csrf != null) {
        Cookie cookie = WebUtils.getCookie(request, "XSRF-TOKEN");
        final String token = csrf.getToken();
        if (cookie == null || token != null && !token.equals(cookie.getValue())) {
            cookie = new Cookie("XSRF-TOKEN", token);
            cookie.setPath("/");
            response.addCookie(cookie);
        }
    }
    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

In general it works fine, the Request header property X-XSRF-TOKEN is send with each request. BUT I have a strange behaviour.
I will update my user- profile in application. The first time it works fine, the second one, I get an HTTP 403 Forbidden and actually I really don't know why.
I do nothing between this two updates (no navigation to other pages between this two updates or something else).

At the picture at the bottom the left Request is the one which works and the right one failes. The only different is that at the right one the property **Set-Cookie** and **X-Application-context** is missing in Response header. The request headers are equal.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here. Its kind of mystic here for me.

[image]

Comment: Can you post your angular code? specifically your angular routes code.

Comment: Is this a common behavior of any 2nd attempt on any resource or just for the profile update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as though there might be some functional `error` in your `front-end` **userProfile.controller**

> Your **Cookie SessionID** redirected form the **request header** is getting same in the **response header** which results in **INVALID_SESSIONID** hence the user is *redirected* to the *login page* or your *signup page*

As a Solution to this you can **either correct your frontend controller** or as another workaround for this you can add the following to your code

- Add the CORS headers only if the CORS is detected and pass the origin header so that to allow access to the user content.
- Respond to the [OPTIONS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP_access_control) request with a http 200 message

  ```
   static final String ORIGIN = "Origin";

  if (request.getHeader(ORIGIN).equals("null")) {
          String origin = request.getHeader(ORIGIN);
          response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");//* or origin as u prefer
          response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
         response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                  request.getHeader("Access-Control-Request-Headers"));
      }
      if (request.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS")) {
          try {
              response.getWriter().print("OK");
              response.getWriter().flush();
          } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
      }
  ```

  Then add the custom filter to be invoked

  ```
        //your other configs
        < security:custom-filter ref="corsHandler" after="PRE_AUTH_FILTER"/>
  ```

*Full attribution goes to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18264334/cross-origin-resource-sharing-with-spring-security) answer by the [author](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3160597/azerafati)*

Comment: thanks for your response. What could be wrong in the ** frontend controller **, if it works the first time?

Comment: The session ID of the first time you login are different and do  not conflict,but the second time you try to update the session ID of the anfrage header conflicts with the antwort header as though they are put same ,hence it is giving invalid session ID and logs out because of security error