# CORS Spring Security configuration - 404 No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-security

I am trying to setup CORS on my Java Spring project.

Separately I have an Angular CLI application with a login page, I would like to authenticate a user using my Spring API.

I am getting the error on the client

```
origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I get this on the server log:

```
No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/authenticateUser]
```

I have tried a number of examples from other threads but the client error doesn't change so I am a bit confused where to configure cors

I have a `AppSecurityConfig` class which `extends` `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class AppSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

    User.UserBuilder users = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder();

    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser(users.username("user1").password("password").roles("ROLE1"))
            .withUser(users.username("user2").password("password").roles("ROLE2"))
            .withUser(users.username("user3").password("password").roles("ROLE3"));
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.cors()
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/loginPageUrl")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticateUser")
            .permitAll();
}
```

My Angular service makes the request:

```
authenticateUser(json: any) {
return this.http.post('http://localhost:8085/authenticateUser'
  , json, {headers : new HttpHeaders()
    .set('Authorization', '')
    });
```

}

The json passed in is:

```
{ username: this.username, password: this.password }
```

Adding the following method to my AppSecurityConfig class resolved the 'No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource' error.

```
@Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:4200"));
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST"));
    configuration.addAllowedHeader("content-type");
    configuration.addAllowedHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin");
    configuration.addAllowedHeader("Authorization");
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion , missing `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header shouldn't have anything to do with an end point missing mapping issue. That might be another issue but not related to CORS.

First you should examine request & response headers in browser network tab ( when UI makes requests to API ) to see if CORS related headers are really missing in response.

These headers begin with - `Access-Control-Allow-*` & the one that controls origin is - `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`

Your security config code , `http.cors()` tries to add a `CorsFilter` as per below logic ( pasting Java Doc of `http.cors()` )

> Adds a CorsFilter to be used. If a bean by the name of corsFilter is
>   provided, that CorsFilter is used. Else if corsConfigurationSource is
>   defined, then that CorsConfiguration is used. Otherwise, if Spring MVC
>   is on the classpath a HandlerMappingIntrospector is used.

So if you don't have provided as what being asked in above then you need to provide that.

Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45997815/3850730) esp. section **3. customize CORS config**

If time permits, go through Spring provided filter `org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter` to understand logic.

Comment: Many thanks. Adding CorsConfigurationSource fixed that issue (added code to post). I now have a 403 response which i'll spend some time looking at.

Comment: @user2670815: To get better help, you can always attach browser screenshot of network tab with as much details as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("http://domain1.com","http://domain2.com"
                    "http://domain3.com");
    }
}
```

Add `addCorsMappings` method to your configuration class and set allowed origins url which are urls of your Angular apps.

In your situation it will be:

```
registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200");
```

to allow requests from Angular app.

Comment: We can use : registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("*");

Comment: Done, get same error on the client. Also WebMvcConfigurerAdapter depreciated notification.

Comment: I noticed I also have "No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/authenticateUser]" on the tomcat log